# Mass Activating Magento Categories

Tags: magento-1.8, category, import

Thanks guys for the help in getting the cat ids in magento.

Found this script to mass enable categories based on IDs

```
<?php setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$file = fopen(MAGENTO . "/var/import/categoriesToEnable.csv", 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
$cats = explode(",",$line[1]);
foreach ($cats as $cat) {
$newcats[$cat] = true;
}
}
// Activate the categories it is in foreach ($newcats as $cat=>$value) {
if ($value && !empty($cat)) {
try {
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat);
if ($_category->getIsActive() === "0" || !$_category->getIsActive()) {
$_category->setIsActive(1);
$_category->save();
echo "
Enabled ".$_category->getName();
unset($_category);
}
} catch(Exception $e) {
echo " Caught Cat Insert exception: ", $e->getMessage();
}
}
 }
?>
```

Get an error when trying to run it

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function setCurrentStore() in /var/www/vhosts/***********/httpdocs/quick_enableCats.php on line 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this way:

```
<?php 
require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$file = fopen(MAGENTO . "/var/import/categoriesToEnable.csv", 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
    $cats = explode(",",$line[1]);
    foreach ($cats as $cat) {
        $newcats[$cat] = true;
    }
}
// Activate the categories it is in foreach ($newcats as $cat=>$value) {
if ($value && !empty($cat)) {
    try {
        $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat);
        if ($_category->getIsActive() === "0" || !$_category->getIsActive()) {
            $_category->setIsActive(1);
            $_category->save();
            echo "Enabled ".$_category->getName();
            unset($_category);
        }
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo " Caught Cat Insert exception: ", $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi

This threw up many more errors.

Comment: what kind of errors, can you mention them?

Comment: Post your errors here